# Dropdownlist bind to list column

Tags: dropdown

I created a form for a new item in a list and I use `asp:dropdownlist`:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1">
<asp:ListItem>choice 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>choice 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I need to save one of the choices in a column.

How do I bind this dropdownlist with a specific column for saving the selected value?

Comment: Are you creating a Visual Web Part? Why aren't you using default list forms?

Comment: Because I have several users and I need that these users see different options by their rights.
Update: I used sharepoint dropdown list with choices, that are taken from other list. That's OK for me. But the problem is by edit form. I have column, in which is stored some value, let's say value 3, in this dropdown I have two choices - value 1 and value 2. But by edit form user can see in dropdown also this value 3 and that's problem for me, is there any way how to hide this value?

Comment: Is JavaScript an option? You can either use JSOM or SPServices (requires jQuery) to provide some client-side validation.

Comment: I'm not sure. What do I need for JS? I have only some rights on the SP server because of company politics. I'm owner of  my created lists, wokflow, etc. but I cannot change server settings.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and JS works. I found JS solutions in other questions and used it in my solution.